# JQuery: how to know the kind of form object we are dealing with?

Tags: jquery

I am building a interactive form and loading the fields according to the answer of the user. Right now I just have two kind of objects "input radio" and "textarea". As I am getting the value of the answers via JQuery, how can I know what object I am dealing with inside the very LAST loaded fieldset?

This is what I am trying:

```
$.fn.getNodeName = function() { // returns the nodeName of the first matched element, or ""
    return this[0] ? this[0].nodeName : "";
};

//var $something = $('input[type=radio]:checked:last');
var $something = $('fieldset:last').parent('nth-child(2)');

//$('#news ul li:first-child').addClass('active');

alert($something.getNodeName());
```

But it's not working...
Thanks.

Comment: "`:radio`" is not an existing pseudoselector in CSS. Perhaps you meant to use an attribute selector for that part instead, e.g. `input[type=radio]:checked:last`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extended your jQuery function to also return the `type`, when the element is an input element:

```
$.fn.getNodeName = function() {
    var elem = this[0]; //Get the first element of the jQuery object
    if(!elem) return "";
    var name = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    return name == "input" ? "input[type=" + elem.type + "]" : name;
};
```

Examples of possible return values:
`textarea`, `input[type=text]`, `input[type=button]`, ...

If you prefer other output formats, just adjust the function. Another method to specify the type is by adding an extra property to the return value, such as:

```
$.fn.getNodeName = function() {
    var elem = this[0]; //Get the first element of the jQuery object
    if (!elem) return "";
    var name = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (name == "input") {
        name.type = elem.type;
    }
    return name;
};
```

Comment: This is an answer! Thank you very much.